# Find linear transformation matrix given equation and bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

If we let $T: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb P_2 $ be the transformation $T(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (x_1+x_2)+(x_2+x_3)x+x_3x^2$, find $[T]_{B,A}$ relative to $A=\{(1,1,1),(1,2,0),(4,0,0)\}$ and $B = \{1,2-5x,3+x^2\}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** follow the usual algorithm. Compute $T(1,1,1)$ and write it as a combination of $1$, $2-5x$ and $3+x^2$. The coefficients are the first column of the matrix representing $T$. Repeat for $T(1,2,0)$ and $T(4,0,0)$ to get the second and third columns.